# cookies is null, on production when use axios from react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, request, credentials

my problem is that, i use different hosting for my cliend side (react) and backend(node js), and i cant get cookies on node server when send request with axios from react, on localhost it working, but on production, dont.. i already use withcredential, i event setheader on server, but nothing helps, what is problem ?

this is my corsoptions on server

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://chemifilmebquotebi.web.app",
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

this is headers which is on server

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "https://chemifilmebquotebi.web.app"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, *");
  next();
});
```

also i use `app.use(cookieParser());`

on front end :

```
const { error, isLoading, data } = useQuery("getQuote",() => axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/movie-list/quote/quote=${quoteId}/get-quote`, { 
    headers: {  
        Accept: "application/json", 
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":  "https://chemifilmebquotebi.web.app/",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,  
    },           
    withCredentials: true,        
}),{ refetchOnWindowFocus: false });
```

this is how i create cookie on front end, when user loged in

```
const expiration = new Date()`
` expiration.setHours(expiration.getHours() + 3);
    cookies.set("token", res.data.token, {
        path: "/",
        expires: expiration,
});
```

when i trying to get cookies in middleware, is says `[Object: null prototype] {}`